# "Table flask_db.user doesn't exist" error when doing db.session.commit()

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building my first app with *Flask Python* micro-framework and I have a problem with committing my models to the database. When I test my User model on the command line, all works well. But when I do a `db.session.commit()`, I have **error 1146 : "Table doesn't exist."**

I'm using a MySQL database in local mode and there is no error with login/password 
Maybe I'm doing it wrong on the configuration or something else. So here is my config application config file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:admin@localhost/flask_db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explains it all-- while you may have the models for your data, you haven't yet created the tables in the database to store and query them.  Simply import your models then run `db.create_all()` to generate the tables and you should be good to go.

It'll be worth you reading the [quickstart guide for Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html) to get your head around the general flow.

Comment: Oh ! i have done it but the rollbacks may have cancel it that's why ... So, thank you very much, it helped :)